# Is there a framework for development virtual reality games with unity 3D

Tags: frameworks, virtual-reality, oculus

I have a virtual reality helmet: Oculus rift Dk2,

I want to develop games for this type of helmet.

Is there a  free framework for this type of helmet  like Immerse Framework (not free)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VRTK supports Occulus SDK - more info here:

- https://github.com/thestonefox/VRTK

You can see some examples built with VRTK here: https://github.com/thestonefox/SteamVR_Unity_Toolkit/blob/master/MADEWITHVRTK.md